# Add Microsoft Exchange account to calendar

Tags: server, calendar, ms-exchange

I need to add my Microsoft Exchange account in order to view my calendar. I suppose I need to configure it via settings. There's an option to add the account in the Settings > Online Accounts > Microsoft Exchange. Typing in my email and password the first thing I notice is that it tries to use wrong server as it should be outlook.office365.com (if I'm correct). That didn't help me much though.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to share a complete 3-Step tutorial to sync your calendar account with Linux.

**Note:** This will also sync your email to evolution, after the tutorial just open evolution and refresh the mailbox - you must have email sync enable on **Online Accounts**.

This tutorial will even work with personalized enterprise domain in office 365.

**STEP 1)** Install **evolution-ews** on your Linux

**Debian and derivated:**

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

or just

```
sudo apt install evolution-ews
```

on newer versions.

**Fedora and Derivated:**

```
sudo yum install evolution-ews
```

or

```
sudo dnf install evolution-ews
```

on newer versions.

**STEP 2)** On **Online Accounts** select **Microsoft Exchange**:

Fill up the email and password fields with your Office 365 info (the rest will be filled automatically).

STEP 3) Replace **Server** field with:

```
outlook.office365.com
```

and copy the **email** field content into **username** field.

Here is how it should look like:

**BEFORE:**
[image: Before]

**AFTER:**
[image: After]

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 and using Unity, the green button to continue doesn't show up, you'lll need change for a moment your login to gnome shell and connect the account.

Comment: turns out you really have to install evolution to make this work

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. On Ubuntu 20.04, using outlook.office365.com didn't work for me. I used "outlook.com" instead (omit the office365 part) and it went through. I hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 11):

Found an answer by trial and error! Type your email in the email field AND in the username field. And of course use outlook.office365.com as the server.

Comment: this worked for me, as well

Answer (score 1):

A followup: with TFA turned on, the answers here are likely missing one step: one needs to generate an app password to use to login as calendar does not support TFA. Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137350/3040064 for more.

Comment: That page seems to have been removed. I managed to follow Microsofts steps on creating an app password [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently installed `Zorin OS Ultimate 15.3` and while connecting my accounts, faced the same issue and found very easy solutions too.

As we're having a custom domain for the exchange account, `Online Account` wasn't able to find the exact username and server while making the connection to the exchange server. And because of that, we are getting the message

```
Error connecting to Microsoft Exchange server:
Code: 4 - Unexpected response from server
```

### How to FIX?

When you get the error message, You'll show the custom option.
You'll need to replace your `username` with the current `email`.

And in the `server` field, you'll need to replace `outlook.office365.com` instead of filled information.

And click on `try again` button.

That's it... The issue will be fixed...