# ubuntu 20.04 calendar does not sync Microsoft Exchange Calendar

Tags: 20.04, calendar

I have signed on my Microsoft Exchange account, with Calendar enabled, [as shown below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGpvX.png)

However, within the Calendar app, I am not able to [sync the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgWcO.png) as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, installing `evolution-aws` solved my problem.

`sudo apt install evolution-ews`

I got my answer: from [Add Microsoft Exchange account to calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115546/add-microsoft-exchange-account-to-calendar)

Comment: Thanks. This was a life-safer for me!